# VB.net download file via ftpwebrequest -> directory topic?

Tags: vb.net

I need to download a file from a FTP Server.
The path and the file name is

```
ftp://10.17.20.60/ata0b/OpconData/StationData/Station.dat
```

When i want to see all Files in the StationData directory i use

```
Dim request As Net.FtpWebRequest = Net.FtpWebRequest.Create("ftp://10.17.20.60/%2F/ata0b/OpconData/StationData/")
request.Method = Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory
request.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential(form1.txtFTPUser.Text, form1.txtFTPPasswort.Text)
Dim response As Net.FtpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()
```

With this i get the content of the directory. Of course i see the Station.dat file. I was able to make it work since i use the %2F parameter to change the directory to ata0b. 
So far so good!

Now i want to download the Station.dat file. But i always get an error  `(550) File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access)` at the last line in code below.

My code looks like this:

```
'Create Request To Download File'
Dim wrDownload As FtpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create("ftp://10.17.20.60/%2F/ata0b/OpconData/StationData/Station.dat")

'Specify That You Want To Download A File'
wrDownload.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile

'Specify Username & Password'
wrDownload.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("opconadmin", "OpconAdmin")

'Response Object'
Dim rDownloadResponse As FtpWebResponse = wrDownload.GetResponse()
```

What's my failure? In my point of view the file must be at the given path. I really hope somebody can give me a hint.

BR
Steffen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means what it says.But let me explain why this might occur :

1 • The file might be unavailable/not present on the server

2 • You might face 'Security Problem on file' issue .

There could be other causes like server timeout or other..

However,you need to find out what the error message really is.TO do this, you can use a `TRY-CATCH` statement. E.g.

```
 Try

 'YOur code here

 Catch e as WebException

 Msgbox(e.Message) 'you can use e.tostring for more details
```

After you find out what exactly is the problem,then you'ld be able to solve it.Take a look at these :

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/76361-file-upload-to-server/

https://nickstips.wordpress.com/2010/10/25/c-ftp-upload-error-the-remote-server-returned-an-error-550-file-unavailable-e-g-file-not-found-no-access/

https://forums.asp.net/t/1777881.aspx

But one thing i'ld like to suggest is to check whether you have any Permission/Security issues or not.And after you get the exact error message,it may(or may not) turn out to be that you don't have enough disk space.However,try my solution and leave a reply for further assistance.

**UPDATE**

Try replacing the FTP link with this : ftp://10.17.20.60//ata0b/OpconData/StationData/Station.da

Comment: The hint with the // after the IP and before the ata0b was the solution.